# Setting form values when jQuery datatable row is clicked

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datatables

I have a web form with a jQuery datatable in it. When a particular row is clicked I get the row data and need to set the values of the controls on the page.

I can get the row values, I set breakpoints and can see the row values fetched are correct but for some reason the control values don't get set (for example, a label's text). This is what I have (watered down version):

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        var zTable = $("#fcTable").DataTable({                
            "bServerSide": true,
            "bDestroy": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "../fc.asmx/GetItems",
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
                aoData.push({ "name": "FacilityID", "value": $('#<%= ddlFacility.ClientID %> option:selected').val() });
            },
            "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                $.ajax({
                    "dataType": 'json',
                    "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "url": sSource,
                    "data": aoData,
                    "success":
                    function (msg) {
                        var json = jQuery.parseJSON(msg.d);
                        fnCallback(json);
                        $("#fcTable").show();
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
                        if (typeof console == "object") {
                            alert(xhr.status + "," + xhr.responseText + "," + textStatus + "," + error);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        $('#fcTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
            var currentRowData = zTable.row(this).data();
            processRow(currentRowData); 
        });

    })
    function processRow(row) {
        debugger
        $("#<%= rblResp.ClientID %> input[type=radio]").prop('checked', false); 
        $("#<%= cblResp.ClientID %> input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked', false); 

        var sQuestion = row[2];

        // None of these sets the label's text
        $('#<%= lblQuestion.ClientID %>').val(sQuestion);
        $('#<%= lblQuestion.ClientID %>').innerHTML = sQuestion;
}
```

**Update**

I can get it to work using

```
$('#<%= lblQuestion.ClientID %>')[0].innerHTML = sQuestion;
```

i.e. adding an array index [0].

But is this the correct way of doing it?

Comment: You might need to render the table again to see the value. It wont display as you set it.

Comment: it is not the value in table I am concerned with. below the table, there is a div with some controls in it. When I select a row, I want to populate those controls based on data in selected row.

Comment: Apparently, I can set it using $('#<%= lblQuestion.ClientID %>')[0].innerHTML = sQuestion; (adding an array index [0]) since jQuery returns an array. Is this the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that ***$('#<%= lblQuestion.ClientID %>')*** returns a jQuery object, and innerHTML is standard JavaScript, and won't work as wanted on a jQuery object.

The ***[0]*** on the end of the object gives you the DOM node (first property of the object), which is what innerHTML needs.

The correct way to do it in pure jQuery would be just:

***$('#<%= lblQuestion.ClientID %>').html(sQuestion);***

FYI, you can set ***ClientIDMode="Static"*** on the input, to avoid asp.Net overriding the ID you give it in your HTML, and so avoid all the <%=... stuff in your JavaScript, which works much better if you get to the point where you want to split the JavaScript out into its own file.